# Tool for modifing STLs?

Tags: 3d-design, software, stl

I'm looking for a tool to modify STL files to make changes, before printing it. I know that it exists, but I don't know the name of the software.

For example, I have a STL file for a ball and I want to modify it to be more egg shaped by extruding or pushing. I'm looking for something like in The Sims games, where I could edit terrains just by clicking mouse and creating holes and hills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sculpting** should be the tool you are looking for.

You can find a lot of sculpting software on the web, including free ones. I personally use Meshmixer and Blender for simple works.

Comment: Thanks you! This is exactly what I look for. I use Meshmixer